Search special character in words like é in Algolia Search
Working on a task where I need to search on Algolia Search
This was working fine for all alphabet text but gave an error for special characters like é
  const index = client.initIndex(indexName);
  return index
    .search("", {
      params: "filters=section_name:Design + Décor",
    })
    .then(({ hits }: any) => {
      console.log(hits)
    });

I am getting the following error
"filters: Unexpected token string(Décor) expected end of filter"

Any guidance towards this appreciated
Thanks in advance

Mina's answer is probably correct for your purposes, but to search for "special" characters, you could use regex \W (ie not a "word" character)

You can use URL encoding to encode the special characters with encodeURIComponent
const index = client.initIndex(indexName);
const sectionName = encodeURIComponent("Design + Décor");
return index
  .search("", {
    params: `filters=section_name:${sectionName}`,
  })
  .then(({ hits }) => {
    console.log(hits)
  });

